# Emerald EV lowering berries not working?

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

I am EV training my lv 45 gyarados so I'm trying to reset (or at the very least estimating how much it has). According to the ribbon girl, it had full EVs already (gave me the effort ribbon) so I started giving it my newly harvested berries.

According to a guide I read (serebii.net), it takes a max of 11 berries to reset your EVs (if your EV is over 100 in a stat, the first berry lowers it down to 100, then 10 every time so 252 EVS will first lower to 100, then 10 every time, making it a total of 11 berries per stat).

I tried this idea to count the EVs of my gyarados and these were the results:

- hp - 80 (8 berries)
- at - 90 (9 berries)
- def - 50 (5 berries)
- spa - 100 (10 berries)
- spdef - 60 (6 berries)
- speed - 160?! <-- 16 berries

Yeah, I was amazed that my gyarados kept eating and lowering down its speed even after 12 berries and went on to 16. I tried to compute the speed EVs depending on its other stat EVs and adding them all up means the speed could have had a max of 130, which makes the 16 berries still way over. How could this have happened? Am I missing something important here?

Comment: Are you sure berries work in the same way as the uh... vitamin drinks (dunno the word, but I mean Calcium, HP UP, etc)? If you max out the vitamins, they do say "this won't have any effect," but I don't think it will do the same for the berries going below the minimum.

Comment: I've never used the EV-lowering berries myself, so I'm not sure if they do stop you. I just figure it's a berry so they'll eat it regardless.

Comment: yup it says it won't have any effect. I fed the gyarados berries until that message, thats why i was able to "count" how much evs it had for the other stats

Comment: Yes, the berries are supposed to drop the EV to 100 if above, then decrease by 10 each time. Don't know what's going on.

Comment: that's totally weird then. i tried to reset and recount the berries i gave and it really did went up to 16. totally weird. maybe it doesn't work that way in emerald? but why would my total EVs be more than 510?

Comment: To tack onto [DisgruntledGoat's explanation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16103/emerald-ev-lowering-berries-not-working/16128#16128), your EVs don't actually total more than 510. Since there is no "Shoot down to 100" in Emerald, what happens is that some of those berries were eaten with less than 10 EVs remaining. It could be as simple as 5 in each stat, actually, to account for the "extra" 30 EVs from the flat sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Pokemon Emerald, each berry lowers EVs by 10. It wasn't until Generation IV (Diamond/Pearl) when the mechanic changed and the first berry reduced EVs to 100. So in theory, Gyarados could scoff 26 of those berries before it gets full ;)

Comment: OHHH so that's why. the guide i was reading didn't point that out. Is there any documentation on this? How did you know about this btw? ( just checking :) )

Comment: Bulbapedia tends to be the go-to source for slightly obscure information. EV page: http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Effort_values